# Spring cloud gateway does not proxy 504 gateway timeout

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a global error handler in a spring boot 3 application built around spring cloud gateway:

```java
@Component
@Order(-99)
public class GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler implements WebExceptionHandler {

    public static final String ERR_TAG_SOURCE = "source";
    public static final String ERR_TAG_CODE = "code";
    public static final String ERR_TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    
    public static final String ERR_SOURCE_INTERNAL = "internal";
    public static final String ERR_SOURCE_UPSTREAM = "upstream";
    
    protected static final String LOG_MARKER = "PROXY";
    protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler.class);

    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {

        LOGGER.error(MarkerFactory.getMarker(LOG_MARKER), "Error ({}) encountered while filtering request {}.", 
                ex.getClass().getCanonicalName(), exchange.getRequest().getId(), ex); 
        HttpStatus status = ex instanceof ErrorResponseException ? (HttpStatus) ((ErrorResponseException) ex).getStatusCode() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        String source = ex instanceof ErrorResponseException ? ERR_SOURCE_UPSTREAM : ERR_SOURCE_INTERNAL;
        String errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(status);
        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(
                Flux.just(
                        exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(
                                (
                                        "{\"" + ERR_TAG_MESSAGE + "\": \"" + errorMessage 
                                        + "\", \"" + ERR_TAG_CODE + "\": " + status.value()
                                        + ", \"" + ERR_TAG_SOURCE + "\": \"" + source + "\"}")
                                    .getBytes())));
    }
}
```

One of the services I proxy occasionally returns 504 gateway timeout. I can see that the global error handler is called - I see the log message written by it. The stack trace looks like this:

```log
2023-06-26 21:19:03,435 ERROR --- pod-86f446c7dd-fn47g parallel-7 com.applicationGlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler: app-name, , , , GATEWAY,  - Error (org.springframework.web.server
.ResponseStatusException) encountered while filtering request f5eb8577-292.
org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT "504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT "Response took longer than timeout: PT5M""
        at com.application.proxy.SomeHandler.lambda$handle$3(SomeHandler.java:66)
        Suppressed: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT "Response took longer than timeout: PT5M"]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/api21/registry/2.1.0/registry/getDataPools" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
                at com.application.proxy.SomeHandler.lambda$handle$3(SomeHandler.java:66)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:278)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:903)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:278)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:278)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
                at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxTimeout.java:341)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
                at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:301)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:280)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:419)
                at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorReturn$ReturnSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorReturn.java:162)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.propagateDelay(MonoDelay.java:271)
                at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:286)
                at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
                at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT "Response took longer than timeout: PT5M"
        at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter.lambda$filter$5(NettyRoutingFilter.java:195)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Flux.java:7123)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorResume$29(Flux.java:7176)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxTimeout.java:341)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:301)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:280)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:419)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorReturn$ReturnSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorReturn.java:162)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.propagateDelay(MonoDelay.java:271)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:286)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.TimeoutException: Response took longer than timeout: PT5M
```

The log level for the entire application is set to DEBUG. There's no other information logged about errors or other operations that transform the response while processing the request which yields the initial 504. However, the response status the client receives isn't the 504 I set in the error handler but a 500. Why?